Is restriction to $p$ Sylow subgroup $\text{res} : H^1(H,M)\to H^1(H_p,M)$ injective?
'Galois cohomology of Algebraic number fields' written by K. Haberland reads the following lemma in page 66.

Let $H$ be a finite group. Let $p$ be a prime number and $H_p$ be a
fixed p Sylow subgroup of $H$.  Let $M$ be finite $H$ module which satisfies
$pM=0$ and $\text{dim}_{\text{F}_p}M\le 2$. Suppose $H$ acts trivially on $M$. Then, restriction map
$\text{res} : H^1(H,M)\to H^1(H_p,M)$ is injective.

When $H_p$ is normal subgroup of $H$, I think it is indeed injective because from inflation restriction sequence, its kernel is $H^1(H/H_p, M)=\text{Hom}(H/H_p,M)=0$.
But how can I prove this is injective in the case $H_p$ is not normal in $H$ ?

I’m assuming that $G=H$ here, and that $H_p$ is a $p$-Sylow?

@Aphelli. Thank you! that's correct.

This is a general phenomenon.
It follows fron the existence, for any $G$-module $M$ (with $G$ a finite group) and any subgroup $H \leq G$, of a natural corestriction map $Cores: H^{\ast}(H,M) \rightarrow H^{\ast}(G,M)$ such that $Cores \circ Res: H^{\ast}(G,M) \rightarrow H^{\ast}(G,M)$ is the multiplication by $[G:H]$.
Indeed, when $H$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$ and $M$ is a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space, then $[G:H]$ is an automorphism of $M$, so $Cores \circ Res$ is injective, hence $Res$ is injective.

I forgot to use $\text{Cores}$, which was my favorite. The condition $\text{dim}_{\Bbb{F}_p} M\le 2$ was not needed. Thank you very much for pointing this out.
